# Rolling average by time period rather than observation in R

Tags: r, time, time-series, summary, moving-average

I have a dataset with dates occurring randomly.  For example:

10/21/15, 11/21/15, 11/22/15, 11/28/15,11/30/15, 12/12/15...etc

I am looking to create a rolling average by time-period NOT by at the observation level.  For instance if I wanted to do a moving average of the last 7 days. I would not want to look up at the last 7 rows, but rather the last 7 *days*

For a tiny example:

```
 dates = c('2015-08-07', '2015-08-08','2015-08-09','2015-09-09','2015-10-10')
 value = c(5,10,5,3,2)
 df=data.frame(dates, value)
 df$desired = c(NA,5,7.5, NA,NA)
```

I am obviously looking to do this for much larger dataset, but I hope you get the idea.  If I was to use 7 days for example this is the result I would expect.

Notice that I don't include the current observations value into the rolling average, only the previous. I want rolling average by time period, not observation row number.

I tried looking at rollmean and dplyr but I couldnt figure it out.  I don't really care how it happens though.

Thanks!

Comment: split the process into multiple parts: 1. aggregate into periods, 2. join to series of all periods to fill potential gaps in your data with NA's, 3. apply rollmean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
rollavgbyperiod <- function(i,window){
  startdate <- dates[i]-window
  enddate <- dates[i]-1
  interval <- seq(startdate,enddate,1)

  tmp <- value[dates %in% interval]
  return(mean(tmp))
}

dates <- as.Date(dates)
window <- 7
res <- sapply(1:length(dates),function(m) rollavgbyperiod(m,window))
res[is.nan(res)] <- NA

> data.frame(dates,value,res)
       dates value res
1 2015-08-07     5 NA
2 2015-08-08    10 5.0
3 2015-08-09     5 7.5
4 2015-09-09     3 NA
5 2015-10-10     2 NA
```

Comment: I have the same need/problem but would like to use a zoo series of dates and values. Is there an easy way to use the rolling average by calendar date with a zoo object? The only way I have found is to used the window function to grab a subset of the series, but I keep thinking there may be a better way.

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct. This would work but you’d obviously have to access the date index of the zoo object rather than having a separate date vector. But, I haven’t tried it yet.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [runner](https://gogonzo.github.io/runner/) package in this case. What is needed here is `mean_run` with `k = 7` window, lagged by 1 period. Simple one-liner:

```
library(runner)
dates = c('2015-08-07', '2015-08-08','2015-08-09','2015-09-09','2015-10-10')
value = c(5, 10, 5, 3, 2)

mean_run(x = value, k = 7, lag = 1, idx = as.Date(dates))
#[1]  NA 5.0 7.5  NA  NA
```

Check [package](https://gogonzo.github.io/runner/) and [function](https://gogonzo.github.io/runner/reference/mean_run.html) documentation